# How to distinct using 2 values from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a multidimensional array in PHP data like bellow. I want to be able to sum the value of 'price' from the same id_gudang and id_receiver.

```
$data = {
    {
        'id_gudang': 69,
        'id_receiver': 121,
        'price': 1
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 69,
        'id_receiver': 121,
        'price': 3
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 71,
        'id_receiver': 134,
        'price': 7
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 72,
        'id_receiver': 135,
        'price': 3
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 72,
        'id_receiver': 216,
        'price': 5
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 72,
        'id_receiver': 216,
        'price': 5
    }
}
```

I want to create new array with the value of 'price' is the sum of the 'price' in the array before. How to sum the value for the same id_gudang and id_receiver? so the result will be:

```
$new_data = {
    {
        'id_gudang': 69,
        'id_receiver': 121,
        'price': 4
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 71,
        'id_receiver': 134,
        'price': 7
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 72,
        'id_receiver': 135,
        'price': 3
    },
    {
        'id_gudang': 72,
        'id_receiver': 216,
        'price': 10
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself yet?  Something like a `foreach()` loop?

Comment: @NigelRen done, but i can only grouping by 1 value, and the real data is more complex. I need something like this query:
$this->db->group_by('id_gudang'); $this->db->group_by('id_receiver');
but for multi array in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $new_data = [];

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $price = $value['price'];
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            if ($key === $k || $value['id_gudang'] !== $v['id_gudang'] || $value['id_receiver'] !== $v['id_receiver']) {
                continue;
            }

            $price += $v['price'];
        }

        $uniqueKey = $value['id_gudang'] . $value['id_receiver'];

        $new_data[$uniqueKey] = [
            'id_gudang' => $value['id_gudang'],
            'id_receiver' => $value['id_receiver'],
            'price' => $price
        ];
    }

    print_r($new_data);

    // print_r(array_values($new_data)); // if you need restart keys
```